# Not able to install team explorer everywhere in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I have Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0)

I am trying to install Team Explorer Everywhere to access TFS for version control purpose..

i am using http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs and https://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs both..

I am getting incompatible version..

When i read the blog it says no more maintenance..This plugin is no longer maintained. It works on the operating system of your choice with Eclipse 4.2

Is there any alternate plugin available which we can work with latest version of eclipse/TFS..

Thanks

Comment: instead of just giving close.. can you give the reason why it needs to be closed.. Earlier eclipse version supported this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Team Explorer Everywhere`  still could be used in Eclipse. I tested it in 2020-06. But this plugin is compatible with java 8, you need to change the configuration of Eclipse.

I guess that you are facing the following issue:

[image: Issue]

To solve this issue, you need to navigate to the Eclipse application folder and find the `eclipse.ini` file.

[image]

You need to set the Eclipse to use java 8 via `-vm Java8 file path/Java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin`

For example:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\kevinliu2\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\kevinliu2\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.16.0.20200615-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin
```

Then restart the Eclipse, the `Team Explorer Everywhere` could work fine again.

[image]

**Updates:**

From [this doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server#cite_note-15):

> If developers do not want to use Microsoft's Team Explorer Everywhere
> plug-in for Eclipse, they can choose to use eGit to connect to TFS.

You can try use [eGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) as a replacement for TEE.

Comment: Are u referring offline installation? ?

Comment: Yes. These operations are on Local machine.  Do you have the same issue as is shown in the answer? Or do I misunderstand you issue?

Comment: I am trying to install this using Eclipse market place or some jar files to put it in eclipse path to do the offline installation

Comment: @ChanGan  I know you means. You could try to install the `Team Explorer Everywhere` in  eclipse. Here are the [detailed steps](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/java/eclipsegit/#:~:text=Choose%20the%20Add%20button%20to,the%20Team%20Explorer%20Everywhere%20plugin.). You also could check the update. Alternative method also exists.